# Using local notation inside a Coq theorem

Tags: coq

Suppose I want to prove a theorem about an object that is verbose to spell out, say `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`, such that the unabbreviated theorem is

```
Theorem verbose :
prop_1 ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
-> prop_2 ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
-> prop_3 ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
-> prop_4 ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
-> prop_5 ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.
```

Is there a way to use local notation inside a theorem, so I can compress it to something like the following?

```
Theorem succinct :
prop_1 X -> prop_2 X -> prop_3 X -> prop_4 X -> prop_5 X
where "X" := ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.
```

I'd use regular notations if I'm using the verbose term repeatedly, but for one-off cases it'd be nice if there were something like `where` for theorems, so I can reuse good names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Section`s and `Let` for local definitions.

```
Section thm.

Let X := ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.

Theorem succinct : prop_1 X -> prop_2 X.

....

End thm.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Definition myobj := ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.` to define a name for the object.  Later, you can use `unfold myobj.` to expand the name to its value.

To introduce it into a local proof environment, use `remember`.

```
Theorem foo:
    forall x y z : Z, x + y - z = x + (y - z).
    intros.
    remember (x+y) as bar.
```

Now the environment is

```
...
Heqbar : bar = x + y
============================
bar - z = x + (y - z)
```

Comment: Maybe the question didn't make it clear, but what I'm looking for is a notation local to a theorem, so that simple variable names like `X` can be reused without overloading. Your suggestion would indeed be the best way if the object was used repeatedly across multiple theorems.

Comment: Inside a proof you can do `remember (foo+bar+ABDE) as Q.`